# scala specs2. equal check relying on toString

Tags: unit-testing, scala, tostring, specs2

This test is OK, because I use `toString` explicitly

```
"have one sentence by '...'" in {

  val text1 = Text("some text...")
  text1.sentences must have size(1)

  text1.sentences(0).toString must_== "some text"
}
```

If without `toSting` the test it fails with message like:

```
Expected :some text
Actual   :some text

java.lang.Exception: 'some text: dictionary.Sentence' is not equal to 'some text: java.lang.String'
```

> I understand the sense of it (in general), but since `toString` is
>   invoked anyway shouldn't it check **string to string** then?
>
> What is the best way to write this test to be concise? Without using
>   `toString` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing `toString` and `equals`.  When you say what you wanted to say:

```
text1.sentences(0) must_== "some text"
```

What you are really saying is:

```
text1.sentences(0).equals("some text") must beTrue
```

If you want this to work, then you would need there to be an `equals` function on the `Sentence` class that used the `toString` of the sentence to compare to the incoming object (a `String` in this case).  A simple spec showing that could look like this:

```
class Sentence(text:String){
  override def equals(obj:Any) = {
    this.toString == obj.toString
  }
  override def toString = text
}

class EqualitySpec extends Specification{
  "A sentence" should{
    "be equal to plain text" in {
      val sentence = new Sentence("hello world")
      sentence must be_==("hello world")
    }
  } 
}
```

Now this works great if that `Sentence` class is your own class.  If it's in a third party library and you have no control over the `equals` function then you might be stuck with things the way that they are.